# Smarty3 upgrade to PHP7 and weird problems with register plugin

Tags: php, smarty, php-7, smarty3, ubuntu-16.04

I have an existing, well functional PHP Application. I am looking into an server upgrade which includes moving from PHP5 to PHP7. As far as I can tell from the documentation Smarty3 should be compatible with PHP7. However, when testing this, it turns out that Smarty refuses to compile the templates after the upgrade.

The source of the problem seems to be this line:

```
$this->smarty->registerPlugin('compiler', 'asset_url',  array(&$this, 'asset_url'));
```

which causes the PHP application to crash like this:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /usr/share/php/smarty3/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 415

Notice: Undefined property: template::$Array in /usr/share/php/smarty3/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 415

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /usr/share/php/smarty3/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:415
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/smarty3/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php(3585): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->compileTag('asset_url', Array)
#1 /usr/share/php/smarty3/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php(4413): Smarty_Internal_Templateparser->yy_r32()
#2 /usr/share/php/smarty3/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php(4515): Smarty_Internal_Templateparser->yy_reduce(32)
#3 /usr/share/php/smarty3/sysplugins/smarty_internal_smartytemplatecompiler.php(118): Smarty_Internal_Templateparser->doParse(3, '}')
#4 /usr/share/php/smarty3/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php(283): Smarty_Internal_SmartyTemplateCompiler->doCompile('<!DOCTYPE html>...')
#5 /usr/share/php/smarty3/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(197): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->compileTemplate(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template))
#6 /usr/share/php/smarty3/sysplugins/sm in /usr/share/php/smarty3/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 415
```

The suspicious line 415 looks like this:

```
 $function = $this->smarty->registered_plugins[$plugin_type][$tag][0];
 if (!is_array($function)) {
     return $function($new_args, $this);
 } elseif (is_object($function[0])) {
     return $this->smarty->registered_plugins[$plugin_type][$tag][0][0]->$function[1]($new_args, $this); <- Crash here!
 } else {
     return call_user_func_array($function, array($new_args, $this));
 }
```

I assume this is some fundamental difference between PHP5 and PHP7 which is biting me, but I can't seem to figure out what it is. Could somebody give me a few pointers to how to sort this out?

Comment: Do you know which exact version of Smarty you're using? There were some fixes for PHP 7 in the 3.1.28 release.

Comment: I am using 3.1.21-1ubuntu1. That is certainly worth investigating!

Comment: @iainn Seems like that was the problem! Could you create an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an older version of Smarty, you might want to update. There were some fixes added in 3.1.28 for PHP 7 compatibility that will probably help with this.

See https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/blob/master/change_log.txt

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of this issue (besides the most common ones like "you have an outdated version") is that in PHP 7 it has been changed the way how code is parsed. In your case:

`$this->smarty->registered_plugins[$plugin_type][$tag][0];`

is [parsed differently in PHP 5 and 7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php):

PHP 5: `$this->smarty->{registered_plugins[$plugin_type][$tag][0]};`

PHP 7: `($this->smarty->registered_plugins)[$plugin_type][$tag][0];`

You can try fixing these code pieces by placing braces and brackets to indicate the parser what are your exact intentions, but I'd suggest you to upgrade Smarty.